# Converting Number to String

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is it possible to convert a number column to a string one , changing '.' for ',' and maintaning two decimal places on QGIS ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do so using the field calculator. The *round* expression converts your number to the needed decimal places, then the *to_string* expression converts to string and the *replace* will replace your dot with a comma.

The expression should look like this:

```
replace(( to_string( ( round( "yourfield", 2)))), '.', ',')
```

**Edit**: this is to address the situation where the number has no decimal digits and the OP wants to pad with 1 or 2 zeros.

Using the field calculator, create a new field with a string type and use the following expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN (length("string") - strpos( "string", ',') = 1) THEN "string" + '0'
WHEN (length("string") - strpos("string", ',') = length("string")) THEN "string" + ',00'
ELSE "string" END
```

Replace "string" with the name of the field you created in the previous step.

To explain a bit what is going on in the expression, *length* returns the number of characters in a string value, *strpos(haystack, needle)* returns the position of *needle* in the given string and finally *"string" + '0'* is a string concatenation expression.

Comment: My answer continue not showing zeros to complete the two decimal places. Do you know where can i be wrong ?

Comment: The expression will only return the significant decimal digits. It will not pad the number with zeros after the decimal point. Doing so will require a conditional expression.

Comment: @DanielGrisotto I have edited my answer with an additional step to address the issue of numbers with 1 or no decimal digits.