# Adding text to end of existing value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, expression

I have a column in a large attribute table. The values in this column are numeric value.

Example entries in this case would be:

```
1, 2.0512, 8.5744, 8.944
```

How can I add the word 'm' to the end of each entry so it'd look like:

```
1m, 2.0512m, 8.5744m, 8.944m
```

I don't want to use the technique of sorting them, then selecting them, then using field calculator to define them. I just want to know how to add text at the end of existing value, no matter what the existing value is.

Comment: This is in ArcGIS in case they are similar: Using Field Calculator, the expression would be something along the lines of `str(!fieldname!) + 'm'`.  The general idea is that you need to convert the numeric value to string and then concatenate with another string.

Comment: Based on this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229786/converting-number-to-string it looks like the function in QGIS to convert a number to string is `to_string` rather than the Python `str`.  But maybe it doesn't have an underscore, per the qgis documentation (look in conversions group) -- https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html

Answer (score 14):

*If your original field is a string-type field, you can update it instead of creating a new field.*

**Use the Field Calculator to update an existing field**

- Check the box next to "Update existing field"
- Select "oldfield" from the dropdown menu
- Use this expression* `concat("oldfield", 'm')`

[image]

---

*If your original field type is numerical, you can't add text to it. Instead you have to add a new string-type field.*

**Use the Field Calculator to create a new field.**

- Output field type: text(string)
- Use this expression* `concat("oldfield", 'm')`

[image]

---

*Substitute the actual name of your field where I used the value "oldfield"

Comment: May work as well `"Field_with_values" || 'm'`